# Can ZT410 printer print 600 dpi?

Tags: dpi, zebra-printer

So, my client asked me to buy a 600 dpi printer (Zebra ZT410) but I don't know much about printers...

Datasheet says ZT410 optionally prints 600 dpi, but is there a different model for each dpi or any ZT410 prints 203/300/600 dpi?

Comment: DPI = dots per inch, so 600 = 600.

Asking about what is available is off topic here and will get this question closed.

Comment: Why don't you reach out to the manufacturer of the printer to confirm?

Comment: Your question is unclear. The title states "any printer", yet the question is specific. :( Can you [edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/1104894/edit) to make it clear, so we can help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means it is an **option** for the ZT410 model. In other words, you have to select that feature and pay extra for it.

See below 203 dpi is much less expensive than the 600 dpi.

[image]

[image]

[Source](https://www.barcodesinc.com/zebra/zt410.htm)